# Curious behavior in sys.path when changing volumes in Windows CMD

Tags: python, windows, cmd

I have just noticed some curious behavior of `sys.path` and Windows CMD and would like to know what is happening and why.

In the following two examples, I print out `sys.path`, change volume to `D:`, `cd` into a directory, change volume back to `C:` and finally print out `sys.path` again.
I do this with two very similar `PYTHONPATH`s.

With `PYTHONPATH=D:\`:

```
C:\Users\z003w3we>python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"
['', 'D:\\', <others>]

C:\Users\z003w3we>D:

D:\>cd UserData

D:\UserData>C:

C:\Users\z003w3we>python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"
['', 'D:\\', <others>]
```

Everything is as expected.

With `PYTHONPATH=D:` (notice the missing trailing `\`):

```
C:\Users\z003w3we>python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"
['', 'D:\\', <others>]

C:\Users\z003w3we>D:

D:\>cd UserData

D:\UserData>C:

C:\Users\z003w3we>python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"
['', 'D:\\UserData', <others>]

C:\Users\z003w3we>echo %PYTHONPATH%
D:
```

Now, instead of `D:`, we suddenly have `D:\UserData` in `sys.path`. Notice that `PYTHONPATH` is unchanged.

I could not reproduce the same behavior with PowerShell; both `PYTHONPATH`s exhibit the first behavior.

As I said, I would be very interested in learning what is going on here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CMD sets a conventionally hidden environment variable named "=D:" for the working directory on drive D:. The Python process inherits this environment variable, and the Windows API uses it when `GetFullPathNameW` is called to resolve the drive-relative path "D:" as a fully-qualified path.

In CMD we can list all environment variables including the 'hidden' ones via set "". This command depends on a bug, but one that's existed for so long that it's now a feature. To list just the hidden ones, use `set "" | findstr /r "^="`. For example:

```
C:\>set "" | findstr /r "^="
=C:=C:\

C:\>cd /d E:\UserData
E:\UserData>c:

C:\>set "" | findstr /r "^="
=C:=C:\
=E:=E:\UserData

C:\>set PYTHONPATH=E:
C:\>python -c "import sys; print(sys.path[1]); sys.exit(0xFF)"
E:\UserData

C:\>set "" | findstr /r "^="
=C:=C:\
=E:=E:\UserData
=ExitCode=000000FF
```

Comment: "D:" is a drive-relative path (i.e. no backslash or slash after the colon) that gets resolved relative to the working directory on the volume. Since an NT process only has one working directory, the classic DOS behavior in which each drive has a working directory is emulated by setting  'hidden' environment variables. If "=D:" isn't set, it defaults to the root directory. Here's another example. If the working directory on "D:" is "D:\UserData", then "D:spam.txt" resolves to "D:\UserData\spam.txt".

Comment: I see. What is PowerShell doing differently?

Comment: I'll check, but I assume PowerShell isn't setting the "=D:" variable. The Windows API uses these drive-letter variables, but it never sets them. It's up to individual applications and libraries to set them. The C runtime library does. Python also does when we call `os.chdir`.

Comment: I can confirm that PowerShell does not set these drive-letter variables, which I tested via `win32api.GetEnvironmentVariable('=C:')` from Python run from  PowerShell run from Explorer. (These 'hidden' variables aren't added to Python's `os.environ` mapping, so we have to use the Windows API directly.) PowerShell doesn't even set its process working directory. It leaves it at the initial value, and all drive working directories are maintained as application state.